# Returning true from a shell pipeline

Tags: shell, makefile, sh, dash-shell

I'd like to conditionally execute a command in a gnu makefile, based on the return value of another command.

To be specific, something like this:

```
lsmod | grep -q pfc && sudo rmmod pfc
```

If the current list of modules as output by `lsmod` contains `pfc`, remove it. This works, with the small problem that if the `grep` command fails (module not present) the whole pipeline returns non-zero, which causes the command to be interpreted as failed, but in fact this is a success.

I could just add a `; true` at the end to always force it to success, but this won't catch failures in the `rmmod` command!

I'd like something that mostly portably across `sh` implementations, but technically I guess I'm using `dash` since that's where `sh` points on Ubuntu.

Comment: Because that pipeline _unconditionally_ returns true. In particular if `rmmod` fails we want to return false, but the above returns true.

Comment: This is only a problem if you are using `set -e`, which is a bad idea precisely because it assumes all non-zero exit statuses indicate an error.

Comment: @chepner - I am not using `set -e`, but the calling application (`gmake`) treats non-zero returns as errors, which makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just handle the expected failure by cleaning the exit value with a nop command like `echo -n`:

```
if lsmod | grep -q pfc; then sudo rmmod pfc; else echo -n; fi
```

Should the output be missing the nop command is executed and the whole line returns with `$?=0`.

**Edit**:
The simpler nop's that were suggested would look like:

```
if lsmod | grep -q pfc; then sudo rmmod pfc; else true; fi
```

resp

```
if lsmod | grep -q pfc; then sudo rmmod pfc; else :; fi
```

Comment: There are simpler nops, like `true` or `:`.

Comment: [And for a standard-compliant shell you don't need any nop at all](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_07)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 bash doesn't accept an empty else branch

Comment: Note this is also an example where an `if` `then` `else` is superior to the shortcutting `&&` and `||`.

Comment: @yacc: `if grep...; then echo...; fi` and if the `if` condition fails no `else` clause is executed and the status is 0.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 This is even a better answer, you should post it.